# Regular expressions with pdfTeX

Tags: pdftex

How can one use `\pdfmatch` with regular expressions and where can one find a listing and description of all the available pdfTeX primitives and help on their use?

**Edit**

The latest issue of the pdfTeX documentation, now contains a small description with examples for the command.

Comment: Unfortunately, many of the pdftex primitives are not properly documented. The pdftex source code seems to be the only definitive reference.

Comment: See patch 375: <http://sarovar.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=106&aid=375&atid=495>.

Comment: @Yiannis: The documentation of Heiko Oberbiek's `askinclude` package has a section on how to use `\pdfmatch`. I have not yet studied this and the source code of `pdftex`, but I will when I get time.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/23d3473d1bfbee80/9e5620948638f596?lnk=gst&q=pdfmatch# --- and --- http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/fa3d97ea41a80294/edf0cfa6aaf16d24?lnk=gst&q=pdfmatch#edf0cfa6aaf16d24  --- have extra pointers (Heiko Oberdiek in both cases). Sorry don't know how to make links in comments.

Comment: @Bruno Thx for the links. (BTW, this is a [Markown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)-enabled website, so `[Markown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)` allows you to put inline web links.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See pdftex 1.30.0 [announcement](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2005-August/005913.html), in particular:

```
  - \pdfmatch [icase] [subcount <number>}] {<pattern>}{<string>}
    Implements pattern matching using the POSIX regex.
    It returns the same values as \pdfstrcmp, but with the following
    semantics: 
      -1: error case (invalid pattern, ...)
       0: no match
       1: match found
    Options:
    * icase: case insensitive matching
    * subcount: it sets the table size for found subpatterns.
      A number "-1" resets the table size to the start default.
  - \pdflastmatch <number>
    The result of \pdfmatch is stored in an array. The entry "0" contains
    the match, the following entries submatches. The positions of the
    matches are also available. They are encoded:
      <position> "->" <match string>
    The position "-1" with an empty string indicates that this entry is not
    set.
```

Answer (score 12):

For regular expressions specifically, the `l3regex` package provides a cross-engine solution (needs eTeX and `\strcmp`).

For instance,

```
\RequirePackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_extract_all:nnN { \w+ } { Hello,~ world! } \l_foo_seq
\seq_show:N \l_foo_seq
```

shows `Hello` and `world` as the two items of the resulting sequence (list).

Here's a list of various questions of whose one answer uses `l3regex`

- [Replace characters in string based on preceding and following character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32151/2707)
- [Substituting strings only when not bounded by letters or numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36350/2707)
- [Extract the numerical and non-numerical portion from text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35250/2707)

Comment: Admittedly, this is shameless self-promotion. But the `l3regex` package was partially written because there is no consistent engine support for regular expressions, so that is on topic here.

Comment: I saw it the other day, looks good, don't you want to give a rather longer example?

Comment: @Yiannis: I'll try to think of better examples (those I put in the doc are rather pointless, since I don't know which applications would be typical `:)`). I gave a longer example (showing only the replacement feature) in answer to a question about [removing dots depending on surrounding characters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32151/2707).