# Extract the numerical and non-numerical portion from text

Tags: macros, strings

I would like to extract the leading number and subsequent text from a string. I have an idea of using the `xstring` package to gobble characters from the right until I end up with a number or an empty string, but wondering if there is an easier way to do it.  The leading number is all the text up until the first character that is not a digit, period, or a plus and minus sign.

Don't really need to worry about error cases such as:

- an additional `+`, `-` within the number
- more digits after first non-numerical digit

So, I should get the following output with the definitions of `\ExtractLeadingNumber` and `\ExtractTralingNonDigits` completed:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*{\ExtractLeadingNumber}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand*{\ExtractTralingNonDigits}[1]{#1}%

% ignore #2 and #3 as those are only needed to produce the desired output
\newcommand{\Test}[3]{#1&\ExtractLeadingNumber{#1}&\ExtractTralingNonDigits{#1}\\}%
%\newcommand{\Test}[3]{#1&#2&#3\\}% This produces desired output

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l r r r}
 & &Number &Non-Digits\\

\midrule
Decimal:
&\Test{ 1.01abc}{ 1.01}{abc}
&\Test{+2.01abc}{+2.01}{abc}
&\Test{-3.01abc}{-3.01}{abc}

\midrule
Integer:
&\Test{  abc}{  }{abc}
&\Test{ 5abc}{ 5}{abc}
&\Test{+6abc}{+6}{abc}
&\Test{-7abc}{-7}{abc}

\midrule
Floating Point:
&\Test{ 5.34abc}{ 5.34}{abc}
&\Test{+6.34abc}{+6.34}{abc}
&\Test{-7.34abc}{-7.34}{abc}

\midrule
Number Only:
&\Test{3}{3}{}
&\Test{3.2}{3.2}{}
&\Test{-5.1}{-5.1}{}
&\Test{+5.1}{+5.1}{}

\midrule
No Digits:
&\Test{abc}{}{abc}

\midrule
Formatted Text:
&\Test{  8$abc_1$}{  8}{$abc_1$}
&\Test{-8.2$abc_1$}{-8.2}{$abc_1$}
&\Test{+$abc_1$}{+}{$abc_1$}
&\Test{$abc_1$}{}{$abc_1$}% no digits
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want a solution using `xstring`, or are you aiming for plain tex?

Comment: @cmhughes: xstring would be fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution with `xstring`:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
% first, need to fix a bug in xstring:
\@xs@newmacro\IfDecimal{}{1}{0}{%
    \@xs@formatnumber{#1}\@xs@reserved@A
    \decimalpart\z@
    \afterassignment\@xs@defafterinteger\integerpart\@xs@reserved@A\relax\@xs@nil
    \expandafter\@xs@testdot\@xs@afterinteger\@xs@nil
    \ifx\@empty\@xs@afterdecimal\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}

\newcommand*\Test[1]{%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{ }{\StrBehind{#1}{ }[\temp@@]}{\def\temp@@{#1}}%
    \IfDecimal\temp@@
        {\def\temp@{#1&#1&}}
        {\def\temp@{#1&}%
        \StrBefore{#1}\@xs@afterdecimal[\temp@@]%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\temp@\expandafter{\temp@@&}%
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\temp@\expandafter{\@xs@afterdecimal}%
        }%
    \temp@\\}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l r r r}
 & &Number &Non-Digits\\
\midrule
Decimal:
&\Test{ 1.01abc}
&\Test{+2.01abc}
&\Test{-3.01abc}

\midrule
Integer:
&\Test{  abc}
&\Test{ 5abc}
&\Test{+6abc}
&\Test{-7abc}

\midrule
Floating Point:
&\Test{ 5.34abc}
&\Test{+6.34abc}
&\Test{-7.34abc}

\midrule
Number Only:
&\Test{3}
&\Test{3.2}
&\Test{-5.1}
&\Test{+5.1}

\midrule
No Digits:
&\Test{abc}

\midrule
Formatted Text:
&\Test{  8$abc_1$}
&\Test{-8.2$abc_1$}
&\Test{+$abc_1$}
&\Test{$abc_1$}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: here is how to do with `\ExtractLeadingNumber` and `\ExtractTralingNonDigits`

```
\makeatletter
% first, need to fix a bug in xstring:
\@xs@newmacro\IfDecimal{}{1}{0}{%
    \@xs@formatnumber{#1}\@xs@reserved@A
    \decimalpart\z@
    \afterassignment\@xs@defafterinteger\integerpart\@xs@reserved@A\relax\@xs@nil
    \expandafter\@xs@testdot\@xs@afterinteger\@xs@nil
    \ifx\@empty\@xs@afterdecimal\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}

\newcommand*\ExtractLeadingNumber[1]{%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{ }{\StrBehind{#1}{ }[\temp@@]}{\def\temp@@{#1}}%
    \IfDecimal\temp@@{#1}{\StrBefore{#1}\@xs@afterdecimal}%
}
\newcommand*\ExtractTralingNonDigits[1]{%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{ }{\StrBehind{#1}{ }[\temp@@]}{\def\temp@@{#1}}%
    \IfDecimal\temp@@{}\@xs@afterdecimal
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\Test[1]{#1&\ExtractLeadingNumber{#1}&\ExtractTralingNonDigits{#1}\\}
```

Comment: This works pretty well. But for my application, I need to be able to extract the two parts separately which is why I had set up the `\ExtractLeadingNumber`, and `\ExtractTralingNonDigits` in the MWE. And since I have not gotten the hang of the `expandafter`, I am not able to adapt this code as is.  So either there should be two separate commands, or perhaps do something like `pgf` does with math where you access `\pgfmathresult` immediately after (i.e., a macro which would use `\renewcommand` to set define the values of two macros.

Comment: I edited the the macro version so that cut-and-paste yields the complete code required. Also, how do I use this in a computation as in `\pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{7 + \ExtractLeadingNumber{123K}}`.  Can you add some detail about the bug that you were fixing here from `xstring`.

Comment: You never said that you wanted to use `\ExtractLeadingNumber{123K}}` in `\pgfmathparse` (the best would be to explain exactly what you want)! Indded, since `\ExtractLeadingNumber{123K}}` is not purely expandable, you cannot write it in the argument of `\pfgmathparse`. You should store the result of `\ExtractLeadingNumber{123K}}` in a macro (for example `\resultextract`) and then write `\pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{7 + \resultextract}`. The "bug" in xstring should have benn fixed a year ago, but I forgot it: a `\detokenize` had to be removed.

Answer (score 12):

An approach using the LaTeX3 `l3regex` module

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,expl3,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_extract_tl
\regex_set:Nn \l_extract_tl { ^\s*([+-]?\d*\.?\d*)\s*(.*) }
\seq_new:N \l_extract_seq
\tl_new:N \NumberValue
\tl_new:N \OtherValue
\cs_new_protected:Npn \extract_number:n #1
  {
    \regex_extract_once:NnN  \l_extract_tl {#1} \l_extract_seq
    \tl_gset:Nx \NumberValue { \seq_item:Nn \l_extract_seq { 2 } }
    \tl_gset:Nx \OtherValue { \seq_item:Nn \l_extract_seq { 3 } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \Test #1
  {
    \extract_number:n {#1}
    & \detokenize{#1} & \NumberValue & \OtherValue
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\ttfamily}r>{\ttfamily}r>{\ttfamily}r}
  \toprule
             & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Input} & 
               \multicolumn{1}{r}{Digit} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{Non-digit} \\
  \midrule
   Decimal:  \Test{ 1.01abc}               \\
             \Test{+2.01abc}               \\ 
             \Test{-3.01abc}               \\
  \midrule
   Integer:  \Test{  abc}                  \\
             \Test{ 5abc}                  \\ 
             \Test{+6abc}                  \\
             \Test{-7abc}                  \\
  \midrule
   Floating Point: \Test{ 5.34abc}         \\
                   \Test{+6.34abc}         \\
                   \Test{-7.34abc}         \\
  \midrule
   Number Only:    \Test{3}                \\
                   \Test{3.2}              \\ 
                   \Test{-5.1}             \\
                   \Test{+5.1}             \\
  \midrule
   No Digits:      \Test{abc}              \\
  \midrule
   Formatted Text: \Test{  8$abc_1$}       \\ 
                   \Test{-8.2$abc_1$}      \\ 
                   \Test{+$abc_1$}         \\
                   \Test{$abc_1$}          \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Currently, this module is 'experimental' hence loading it separately from `expl3`, but I'd expect it to move to 'kernel' in the near-ish future (before the end of the year).

The way that this works is that when we do a regular expression match, the capturing groups are stored in a sequence indexed from 0 (the complete match) upward. So I've got the first capture group as the numerical part and the second as the non-numerical. Notice that I've also included `\s*` to remove any leading spaces from those two groups: if you miss that out then you'll also pick up the spaces as part of the match.

Also notice that the results here are detokenized, so if you want to have formatted text you'd need to `\scantokens` the results. (Something as simple as `\scantokens\expandafter{\OtherValue}` would do here.)

Comment: In the CTAN version, I think we have `\regex_extract:NnN` rather than `\regex_extract_once:NnN`. This will change at the weekend, as I'm due a CTAN snapshot.

Comment: Notice that I've used a 'pre-compiled' regex here as it's used many times and performance can therefore be gained by setting up the regex first. You use `\regex_extract_once:nnN` with a 'one-use' regex.

Comment: Seems to work fine once I change `\regex_extract_once:NnN` to `\regex_extract:NnN` in the MWE. I guess I am going to have to learn this syntax one of these days.

Comment: @PeterGrill As I said, I'll update CTAN probably tomorrow to deal with that. Of course, someone could convert Bruno's code to non-LaTeX3 syntax (in this case it might not be so bad as a lot of the code is primitives).

Comment: @Joseph or someone can simply write a LaTeX2e-like wrapper for that module. `\def\ExtractOnce{\@ifstar\regex_extract_once:NnN\regex_extract_once:nnN}` etc.

Comment: The “nearish future” has arrived!

Answer (score 11):

If you can use luatex, you may use a proper parser (the code below is in ConTeXt, just because I don't know all the details of using luatex in LaTeX).

```
 \startluacode
  local P, R, S, V, match = lpeg.P, lpeg.R, lpeg.S, lpeg.V, lpeg.match
  local Ct, C, Cs, Cc = lpeg.Ct, lpeg.C, lpeg.Cs, lpeg.Cc

  local format = string.format

  local digit    = R("09")
  local sign     = S('+-')
  local integer  = sign^0 * digit^0 -- NOTE: I'd rather use digit^1, but
                                    -- the requirements want to capture a
                                    --  single sign as well
  local float    = sign^0 * digit^0 * P('.') * digit^1
  local space    = P(" ")^0

  local number   = Cs(float + integer)
  local any      = Cs(P(1)^0)

  local number_value = Cc("\\global\\def\\NumberValue{%s}") * number / format
  local other_value  = Cc("\\global\\def\\OtherValue{%s}")  * any    / format
  local parser = Cs(space * number_value * other_value)

  function commands.extract_number(s)
      context(match(parser,s))
  end
\stopluacode

\unprotect
\def\extract#1%
    {\let\NumberValue\relax
     \let\OtherValue \relax
     \ctxcommand{extract_number(\!!bs\detokenize{#1}\!!es)}}
\protect
```

You can then use this as follows.

```
\def\Test#1%
    {\extract{#1}%
     #1 \NC \NumberValue \NC \OtherValue}

\starttext

\starttabulate[|l|r|r|r|]
  \HL
  \NC           \NC Input \NC Digit \NC Non-Digit \NC \NR
  \HL
  \NC Decimal:  \NC \Test{ 1.01abc}               \NC \NR
  \NC           \NC \Test{+2.01abc}               \NC \NR 
  \NC           \NC \Test{-3.01abc}               \NC \NR
  \HL
  \NC Integer:  \NC \Test{  abc}                  \NC \NR
  \NC           \NC \Test{ 5abc}                  \NC \NR 
  \NC           \NC \Test{+6abc}                  \NC \NR
  \NC           \NC \Test{-7abc}                  \NC \NR
  \HL
  \NC Floating Point: \NC \Test{ 5.34abc}         \NC \NR
  \NC                 \NC \Test{+6.34abc}         \NC \NR
  \NC                 \NC \Test{-7.34abc}         \NC \NR
  \HL
  \NC Number Only:    \NC \Test{3}                \NC \NR
  \NC                 \NC \Test{3.2}              \NC \NR 
  \NC                 \NC \Test{-5.1}             \NC \NR
  \NC                 \NC \Test{+5.1}             \NC \NR
  \HL
  \NC No Digits:      \NC \Test{abc}              \NC \NR
  \HL
  \NC Formatted Text: \NC \Test{  8$abc_1$}       \NC \NR 
  \NC                 \NC \Test{-8.2$abc_1$}      \NC \NR 
  \NC                 \NC \Test{+$abc_1$}         \NC \NR
  \NC                 \NC \Test{$abc_1$}          \NC \NR
  \HL
\stoptabulate
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I can show the plain TeX solution of this problem for the sake of completeness.

```
\def\separeparts#1{\def\firstpart{}\def\listchars{0123456789.}\separepartsA#1\end}
\def\separepartsA#1{\isinlist{+-}#1%
   \iftrue
      \def\firstpart{#1}\expandafter\separepartsB
   \else 
      \def\next{\separepartsB#1}\expandafter\next
   \fi
}
\def\separepartsB#1{\isinlist\listchars#1%
   \iftrue
      \addto\firstpart#1%
      \ifx.#1\def\listchars{0123456789}\fi
      \expandafter\separepartsB
   \else
      \def\next{\separepartsC#1}\expandafter\next
   \fi
}
\def\separepartsC#1\end{\def\secondpart{#1}}
```

Note that the list of allowed digits `\listchars` includes decimal point but if decimal point is found then `\listchars` is redefined because the second decimal point isn't allowed.

This code needn't any package, only two macros from `opmac.tex` is used. You can copy and paste these macros from `opmac.tex` or from here:

```
\def\isinlist#1#2#3{\def\tmp##1#2##2\end{\def\tmp{##2}%
   \ifx\tmp\empty \csname iffalse\expandafter\endcsname \else
                  \csname iftrue\expandafter\endcsname \fi}% end of \def\tmp
   \expandafter\tmp#1\endlistsep#2\end
}
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
```

Now, you can do tests:

```
\def\test#1{\separeparts{#1}
   \immediate\write16{"#1" = "\firstpart" and "\secondpart"}
}

\test{+2.01abc}   % output: "+2.01abc" = "+2.01" and "abc"
\test{-3.01abc}   % output: "-3.01abc" = "-3.01" and "abc"

\test{  abc}      % output: " abc" = "" and "abc"
\test{ 5abc}      % output: " 5abc" = "5" and "abc"
\test{+6abc}      % output: "+6abc" = "+6" and "abc"

\test{1.23.36abc} % output: "1.23.36abc" = "1.23" and ".36abc"
```

You can use this code in plain TeX, in LaTeX or in ConTeXt. It doesn't matter. The code is based only on TeX primitives.