# Using control sequence as part of key names in property list

Tags: expl3, l3prop

Adapting Joseph's answer in [Extract the numerical and non-numerical portion from text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35250/extract-the-numerical-and-non-numerical-portion-from-text) to count a non-numerical portion from a text. The idea behind my method is to use regex to seperate the numerical and symbolic part from a text (like in the answer), and store the symbolic and numerical parts as key names and values respectively in a property list. This works perfectly fine. The problem I ram into is when an input is a control sequence like `\alpha` and sub/superscipt `_` and `^`. The code shows this issue e.g. `\test{\alpha}` does not produce `\alpha` (the symbol).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
{
    \simon_test:n {#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \simon_test:n #1
{
    \prop_clear:N \l_tmpa_prop
    \exp_args:NNn \prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop {#1} {} % the value is of no importance for the mwe

    \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop
    {
        ##1
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\test{a_n}$ should be $a_n$

$\test{b^2}$ should be $b^n$

$\test{\alpha}$ should be $\alpha$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe this is due to l3prop stores the key names as strings.

The use of a property list in this way is an core part of my code (I could rewrite it to use two sequences, but I found property list easier to use). Is there a way to overcome this, or do I have to rewrite my code?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a property list for this, as you assign no value to any key.

Comment: @egreg In my actual code I do (It's just way too long for an MWE).

Comment: Yes, key names are strings: broadly, you should be using them to _look stuff up_, not expecting to typeset them. Use an appropriate structure: I'd likely go for a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind property list is that it stores key-value pairs and the key is treated as a string (in the `expl3` technical sense). Using keys as values is wrong to begin with.

Besides, using `\prop_map_inline:Nn` doesn't guarantee a precise order, so it should be used to *set* other things, not generally for typesetting (unless you don't care about the order or never modify the values once the `prop` is set).

Use `\tl_rescan:nn`, but keep in mind there can be some secondary issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
{
    \simon_test:n {#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \simon_test:n #1
{
    \prop_clear:N \l_tmpa_prop
    \prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop {#1} {} % the value is of no importance for the mwe

    \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop
    {
      \tl_rescan:nn { } { ##1 }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\test{a_n}$ should be $a_n$

$\test{b^2}$ should be $b^n$

$\test{\alpha}$ should be $\alpha$
\end{document}
```

I removed `\exp_args:Nnn` that does nothing at all. It exists for technical reasons, but it's not even documented.

[image]

Alternatively, you can set an auxiliary property list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
 {
  \simon_test:n {#1}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \simon_test:n #1
 {
  \prop_clear:N \l_tmpa_prop
  \prop_clear:N \l_tmpb_prop
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop {#1} {} % the value is of no importance for the mwe
  \prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpb_prop {#1} {#1}
    \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop
    {
      \prop_item:Nn \l_tmpb_prop { ##1 }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\test{a_n}$ should be $a_n$

$\test{b^2}$ should be $b^n$

$\test{\alpha}$ should be $\alpha$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tl_rescan:nn` worked in my code, but if it can cause problems I'm not aware of, it might not be the ideal way to go. I might aswell go with one sequence for symbols and one sequence for values.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a sequence for storing the 'symbols' here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
{ \simon_test:n {#1} }

\seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \simon_test:n #1
  {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {##1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\test{a_n}$ should be $a_n$

$\test{b^2}$ should be $b^n$

$\test{\alpha}$ should be $\alpha$
\end{document}
```

though one could also put the data itself into the property list (more complex, and probably needing a full use case to be sure if it's the best plan).

Comment: It was a sheer coincidence that I discovered property list stored the key names as strings. I think you are right, using sequence are the way to go here. Maybe I will post a new question with a full use case in the future.