# Substituting strings only when not bounded by letters or numbers

Tags: strings, xstring

Using `StrSubstitute` from `xstring` I can find and replace matches. For e.g.:

`\StrSubstitute{I like to eat fish.}{fish}{apples}` gives "I like to eat apples."

`\StrSubstitute{Do you want to eat?}{eat}{fly}` gives "Do you want to fly?"

- How can I adjust this so that the replace only occurs when the matching string not bounded by letters or numbers?

For e.g., when replacing "fish" with "apples":

`I like to eat fish.` gives "I like to eat apples." (changed)

`I like to go fishing.` gives "I like to go fishing." (not changed)

`@fish are interesting/.` gives "@apples are interesting." (changed)

`9fish is too many.` gives "9fish is too many." (not changed)

In the above cases, the changes did not occur in situations when the letters (A-Z or a-z) or number (0|+) appeared on either side.

Comment: Have a look at experimental `l3regex` package. It provides regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `l3regex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\replaceall[3]{
  \str_set:Nn \l_temp_str {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {#2} {#3} \l_temp_str
  \l_temp_str
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\replaceall{foo and foo and afoo and foo0 and 123foo123 and foo}{(\W|^)foo(\W|$)}{\1bar\2}
% result:
% bar and bar and afoo and foo0 and 123foo123 and bar
\end{document}
```