# Macro for a code translator

Tags: macros, token-lists

Is there an existing macro that "translate" tokens using some code ?
For example :

```
\def\code{{{a,b},{b,c},{c,a}}}
\translate[\code]{caac} % => would typeset "abba"
```

or even better something like that :

```
\def\code{{{ab,ba},{ac,ca},{b,c}{c,b}}}
\translate[\code]{abbcac} % => would typeset "bacbca"
```

The syntax for the code definition is not important.

If there is no such macro, any proposition is welcomed to obtain
an efficient solution to this problem.

Thank you :)

Comment: What I have seen is using `etoolbox` to replace certain tokens in a macro.

Comment: This is probably doable with regular expressions. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4347/regular-expressions-with-pdftex for a starting point. There are also regex questions and answers on stackoverflow. Regular expressions have a steep learning curve leading to a big payoff.

Comment: In fact, we need some kind of parsing strategy. Regexp can be used for such a thing but are not useful for doing the parse itself...

Comment: TikZ/PGF provides (and uses) a parser module...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(edit: first parser of my initial answer was not using the right rules.)*

Here's a TikZ/PGF solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgfmodule{parser}

\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter a}{b}
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter b}{c}
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the letter c}{a}
\pgfparserdef{myparser}{initial}{the character ;}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}


\pgfparserdef{myparser2}{initial}{the letter a}{\pgfparserswitch{s2}}
\pgfparserdef{myparser2}{s2}{the letter b}{ba\pgfparserswitch{initial}}
\pgfparserdef{myparser2}{s2}{the letter c}{ca\pgfparserswitch{initial}}
\pgfparserdef{myparser2}{initial}{the letter b}{c}
\pgfparserdef{myparser2}{initial}{the letter c}{b}
\pgfparserdef{myparser2}{initial}{the character ;}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}

\newcommand\myparserone[1]{%
  \expandafter\pgfparserparse\expandafter{\expandafter myparser\expandafter}#1;%
}

\newcommand\myparsertwo[1]{%
  \expandafter\pgfparserparse\expandafter{%
    \expandafter myparser2\expandafter}#1;%
}

\begin{document}
\textbf{\pgfparserparse{myparser}caac; \pgfparserparse{myparser2}abbcac;}
\emph{\myparserone{caac} \myparsertwo{abbcac}}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: parsers results]

Comment: Thanks, this is a really nice solution. This would be even better if we can produce the parser automatically from the code...

Comment: @Xoff: citation: "*The syntax for the code definition is not important.*" ;-)

Comment: You're right, and it is enough for what I need. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

A reasonably efficient implementation of the first one is

```
\def\translate[#1]#2{{%
\expandafter\xlc#1\relax
\lowercase{#2}}}

\def\xlc#1{%
 \ifx\relax#1\else
 \xxlc#1%
 \expandafter
 \xlc
 \fi}

\def\xxlc#1,#2{\lccode`#1=`#2 }

\def\code{{a,b}{b,c}{c,a}}

\translate[\code]{caac}


\bye
```

which typesets abba if run through plain TeX.

Comment: This is not as general as I hoped, but it's very nice to use the lowercase macro to achieve the goal, I like it :)